# Populate select drop-down based on choice of another select form field

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my fiddle : [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/60w7yj0k/8/)

Under the "Rules" Tab, on click of "+" a group of form-fields are cloned i.e, Join operator, Attributes, Operator & Threshold.

The attribute drop down is populated using a json (called expressionDetails) created using the relationship between contracts and thresholds variables.

Based on the choice of attributes, the thresholds field will be populated.

I could achieve this for the non-cloned Attribute and Threshold. However, due to class/ id duplication I am not able to pick up the cloned attribute's value as all the clones attributes hold the same class and their values are getting concatenated (in var z1).

```
//Appending option to "cloned" thresold field based on choice of attribute
$('.attributeExpr').on('change', function(e) {
    $('.thresholdExpr').empty();
    var z1 = $(".attributeExpr option:selected").text();                    
    console.log(z1);
    var a1 = expressionDetails[z1];
    console.log(a1);
    for (var i1 = 0; i1 < a1.length; i1++) {
        var b1 = a1[i1].name;
        //  alert(b1);
        var opt1 = $("<option>").text(b1);
        //  console.log(opt1);
        $('.thresholdExpr').append(opt1);
    }
});
```

Is there a different approach for this? Also, it should work for every cloned group thereafter as I will be using all of these values to create the "Expression" field.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line 3 in above code with this. it will only return selected value.

```
var z1 = $("option:selected",$(this)).text();
```

Comment: It does work in choosing attribute options and populating thresholds. But, when you have multiple cloned groups, changing one attribute dropdown option changes all of the thresholds selected value , too. Hope my words were understood.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
var z1 = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
```

Instead

```
var z1 = $(".attributeExpr option:selected").text();
```

Try this, I have tested it in your fiddle DEMO and it is working.

```
$('.attributeExpr').on('change', function(e) {
  var index = $(this).index('.attributeExpr');
  $('.thresholdExpr:eq( '+index+' )').empty();
  var z1 = $(this).find("option:selected").text();                  
  console.log(z1);
  var a1 = expressionDetails[z1];
  console.log(a1);
  for (var i1 = 0; i1 < a1.length; i1++) {
    var b1 = a1[i1].name;
    //  alert(b1);
    var opt1 = $("<option>").text(b1);
    //  console.log(opt1);
    $('.thresholdExpr:eq( '+index+' )').append(opt1);
  }
});
```

I have added index so it can target the current element.

Comment: It does work in choosing attribute options and populating thresholds. But, when you have multiple cloned groups, changing one attribute drop-down option changes all of the thresholds drop-down values , too. Hope my words were understood

Comment: Yes, it works great! Thanks so much. Also, could you please help me a little in creating an expression based on the chosen values of both non-clone and cloned form fields? [e.g temperature > TEMP-TH-25 && humidity != HUM-TH-25 || humidity >= .....]

Comment: Glad I could help, sure let me know what you need to do and if I can I will help you.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should do to make it work properly specially such complex implementation is to make the `expressionsBuilder formgroup option fields` to be dynamic, means it is being populated by JavaScript and not hard-coded in your HTML.

Then, you will assign the `change` event listener for each individual fields you created, this way you can control every form-group's behavior.

[example click here](https://jsfiddle.net/4k8d2ez8/4/)

by populating it programatically you have total control of the fields behavior. You can then get each and every value of fields by iterating `expressions` variable like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < expressions.length; i++)
{
  var id = expressions[i];
  var theAttribute = $("#" + id).find("[name='attribute']").val();
  var theOperator  = $("#" + id).find("[name='operator']").val();
  var theThreshold = $("#" + id).find("[name='threshold']").val();
}
```

Hope that helps

===

**ALSO** heads up, it appears you are creating such complex application. I am suggesting you should make use for JavaScript frameworks to ease up maintainability of your code. This approach will become very hard to maintain in the long run

Comment: Hi thanks for your efforts. Did you notice clicking "add" or "remove" after choosing your options resets the previously selected dropdowns too?

Comment: @masterpreez : Hi, I recommend you to not change the structure of data for the application. I am using the variables for JSON in the fiddle while in the actual scenario, it comes from an ajax call made to an API. Could you please use my fiddle with no changes made to "contracts" and "thresholds" which are the data variables?